# Ubuntu man page ambiguity

Tags: ubuntu, manpage

There are certain C functions whose names are ambiguous with the Ubuntu commands eg: getopt. How do I view the man page of these functions? No doubt it is easily available on the internet but I am keen to not leave the terminal as far as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the format `man [section] name` (e.g. `man 3 getopt`) where *section* can be one of the followings:

```
   1      User Commands
   2      System Calls
   3      C Library Functions
   4      Devices and Special Files
   5      File Formats and Conventions
   6      Games et. Al.
   7      Miscellanea
   8      System Administration tools and Deamons
```

Consult `man man` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`man 3 getopt` shows the manpages for C getopt.

see `man man`

Answer (score 1):

`man 3 getopt` gives c function information. 
where as `man 1 getopt` or `man getopt` gives command information.

Pages are traditionally referred to using the notation "`name(section)`": for example, `ftp(1)`. The same page name may appear in more than one section of the manual, as when the names of system calls, user commands, or macro packages coincide.

Answer (score 1):

`man -wa getopt` gives you the list of manual pages for `getopt`: in my system, it is:

```
/usr/share/man/man1/getopt.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man3/getopt.3.bz2
/usr/share/man/man3p/getopt.3p.bz2
```

Or, alternatively, `man -f getopt`:

```
getopt               (1)  - parse command options (enhanced)
getopt               (3)  - Parse command-line options
getopt []            (1)  - parse command options (enhanced)
getopt []            (3)  - Parse command-line options
getopt []            (3p)  - command option parsing
```

You can then select the right manual page by using the number that is in the filename (in the first output) or in between parenthesis (in the second output): for example, `man 1 getopt` or `man 3 getopt`.

Answer (score 1):

`$ man 3 getopt` where `3` is section.

`$ man man`

As [Sections.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) states:

*The manual is generally split into eight numbered sections, organized as follows (on BSD, Unix and Linux):*

```
Section     Description
 1.         General commands
 2.         System calls
 3.         Library functions, covering in particular the C standard library
 4.         Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
 5.         File formats and conventions
 6.         Games and screensavers
 7.         Miscellanea
 8.         System administration commands and daemons
```

*Unix System V uses a similar numbering scheme, except in a different order:*

```
Section     Description
 1.         General commands
 1M.        System administration commands and daemons
 2.         System calls
 3.         C library functions
 4.         File formats and conventions
 5.         Miscellanea
 6.         Games and screensavers
 7.         Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
```